# Set a UITabBarController delegate in a UIStoryboard

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I've been searching for this, can't find the answer.

I'm setting up a `UIStoryboard` in Interface Builder, and while everything is working fine, I seem to be unable to hook up the `delegate` outlet of the `UITabBarController` to any of the `UIViewController`'s in the `UIStoryboard`, regardless of their position in the `UIStoryboard`. I've set the `UIViewController`'s to be a `<UITabBarControllerDelegate>` in the `.h` file, but Interface Builder won't allow me to select the `UIViewController` as the `delegate` for the `UITabBarController`.

Has anyone run into this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out that the reason you can't set the `delegate` in the `UIStoryboard` is because you have no guarantee that the `UIViewController` is loaded before the `UITabBar` is loaded. Therefore, programmatically setting the `delegate` (in a different `UIViewController`) is the ***ONLY*** way to accomplish this.

Comment: None that I've found. You can definitely test it out though.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to do it programmatically in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of your application delegate:

`_tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)_window.rootViewController;
    _tabBarController.delegate = self;`

Comment: I know how to do it programmatically, why can't I do it in Interface Builder?

Comment: One of the answers at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175661/set-uitabbarcontroller-created-in-interface-builder-as-delegate

Comment: This answer works, but assumes that the rootviewcontroller is currently the tab bar controller you wish to set the delegate of. This isnt necessarily the case if you have other view controllers etc in the app.