# Set UITabBarController created in Interface Builder as delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, uitabbarcontroller

I created my iOS app with Tab Bar template, so here is UITabBarController with bar buttons. An issue is how to set it as delegate. I found at SO that it has to be set programmatically in AppDelegate, but I believe it's impossible, because I've got no access to Tab Bar Controller as outlet.

I added proper value to `@interface` (both ViewController and AppDelegate), but doesn't know what to do next.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>
```

I hope I don't have to get rid of whole app template and it's possible to set Tab Bar Controller created in IB to be delegate.

Exactly I want to make it delegate to create on tab select event like this:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't remember exactly the Xcode's Tab Bar template set up, but in your AppDelegate you can access to your window's `rootViewController`, cast it to a `UITabBarController`, and then set its delegate to your AppDelegate or to any other view controller.

Something like this:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = 
    (UITabBarController *)[[self window] rootViewController];
[tabBarController setDelegate:self]; // In this example your app delegate would implement the UITabBarControllerDelegate protocol.
```

EDIT

If you want to set your ViewController instance as the delegate:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = 
        (UITabBarController *)[[self window] rootViewController];
// I assume you have your ViewController instance set as the first view controller of your tab bar controller
// No need for a cast here since objectAtIndex: returns id, but of course you must implement the UITabBarController protocol in your ViewController.
    [tabBarController setDelegate:[[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]]];
```

EDIT 2
From your ViewController itself you can set the tab bar controller's delegate as rdelmar comments. 
Just keep in mind that this cannot be done in the init method because the view controller is not in the tab bar controller yet. The proper place would be `viewDidLoad` but therefore it will not be executed until the ViewController view loads...

```
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
```

Comment: I tried this, but it seems to doesn't work. I believe that this way is correct (there is no error or warnings), but `tabBarController: didSelectViewController` doesn't fire when tab is changed.

Comment: Just noticed my fault. It fires but has to be placed in AppDelegate.m. So there is no way to make it work inside ViewController.m?

Comment: Where are you implementing tabBarController:didSelectViewController:? In your app delegate, right? Can you debug and check that tabBarController is not nil?

Comment: @e1985         tabBarController is not nil and my tabBarController:didSelectViewController: is in AppDelegate (I believe it cannot work in ViewController). Although I'd like to use this event in ViewController, but it seems to be impossible, right?

Comment: I tried your code from edit but it makes error: No visible @interface for 'UITabBarController' declares the selector 'setDelegate:objectAtIndex:'

Comment: Your ViewController can be the tab bar controller delegate, no problem with that. You only need to implement that delegate method once(the tab bar controller calls in only on one object - its delegate), and as you say you want it to be your ViewController instance.

Comment: PS In fact there is one too many ] at the end of the line. Just for others visited this post ;)

Comment: @PiotrSochalewski,  this is  kind of a convoluted way to do it. From any controller that's in one of the tabs, you can just write: self.tabBarController.delegate = self; There's no need to access the  window's root view controller, or the tab bar controller's viewControllers array.

Comment: rdelmar's argument is correct, I did not realize it since originally my code was ment to set the app delegate as the tab bar delegate. Edited.

Answer (score 8):

You can quickly and easily create a new TabBarController Delegate class and connect it as the delegate in the storyboard.

1. Create a new class :

   class TabBarControllerDelegate: NSObject, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
2. In IB, add an object from the object library to the list of View Controller on the left (note: search "object", it's a yellow cube).
3. Change the class of this object (your yellow cube in IB) to TabBarControllerDelegate
4. In IB navigate to your Tab Bar Controller Scene.  From the Connection Inspector, drag the delegate circle to the new object you added in Step 3.
5. Implement your delegate methods in your TabBarControllerDelegate class.  Done!

   ```
   func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController)->Bool {
      println("Selected a new tab")
   ```

   }

Comment: From far, a solution involving no code is the best solution.

Answer (score 5):

## 0 lines of code

**Drag an Object and subclass it**

[image: IB Object]

1. Xcode > Show File Inspector > Custom Class.
2. **Class**: `TabBarControllerDelegate`.

---

**Set delegate to that Object**

[image: Link to object in IB]

---

**Put your existing code in that Object**

This is the code you *already have* in your current `UITabBarControllerDelegate`.

```
class TabBarControllerDelegate: NSObject, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    // Delegate code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What about create a `viewController` lets say `MyTabController` subclass `UITabBarController`

```
@interface MyTabController : UITabBarController<UITabBarControllerDelegate>
```

and set the tab Controller's class in you `storyboard` to `MyTabController` instead of `UITabBarController`,  then put  `self.delegate = self;` in your `viewDidLoad`

implement:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

and here you are.

**Edit:**

If you find `self.delegate = self;` is odd, which it is, you can create an outlet in your `MyTabController`

```
IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController; and connect it to the tab controller in your storyboard.
```

Then you can put `tabBarController.delegate = self;`

Comment: I don't see the need of creating a UITabBarController subclass for this case and don't like the idea of an object being its own delegate .

Comment: This is better than adding code to your appDelegate, you will have a better control over your VC, beside it works fine man. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065605/didselectviewcontroller-method-not-being-called-with-storyboard/13033372#13033372

Comment: As I say, I don't think it's a good design to have a  UITabBarController subclass for what the question asks, and cannot see how you will have a better control over your VCs. About an object implementing its own delegate, check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310287/can-an-objective-c-object-be-its-own-delegate-is-it-good-programming-practice

Comment: Also I don't see the point of your edit - you want to create a tabBarController outlet and set it to self via IB for what?